# Comprobar si un input esta vacio con Typescript Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, validación, entrada

es que tengo una serie de inputs los cuales van a variar la clase del padre si estos están vacíos o no. Necesito hacerlo con typescript en Angular 6 y la verdad soy nueva en angular.

A continuación copio el código HTML y Typescript que intento ajustar

gracias.

HTML:

```
<label class="at-input-label" [ngClass]="{'active': animation==true}">
  <span>{{inputTitle}}</span>
  <input type="text" id="empty" class="at-input-textfield" [(ngModel)]="value" (focus)="animation=true" (focusout)="animation=false">
  <small>{{textHelper}}</small>
</label>
<!--Active-->
<label class="at-input-label active">
  <span>{{inputTitle}}</span>
  <input type="text" name="" value="Text here" class="at-input-textfield">
  <small>{{textHelper}}</small>
</label>
<!--Disabled-->
<label class="at-input-label disabled">
  <span>{{inputTitle}}</span>
  <input type="text" name="" class="at-input-textfield" disabled>
  <small>{{textHelper}}</small>
</label>
<!--Error-->
<label class="at-input-label active error">
  <span>{{inputTitle}}</span>
  <input type="text" name="" value="Text here" class="at-input-textfield">
  <small>Error Text</small>
</label>
```

Typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forms',
  templateUrl: './forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forms.component.scss']
})

export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {
  public inputTitle: string;
  public textHelper: string;
  public selectedValue: string;
  public items: string;
  public animation: boolean;
  //public value: any;

  constructor() {
    this.inputTitle = 'Textfield';
    this.textHelper  = 'Text helper';
    this.selectedValue = "";
    this.items = [
      { value: "0", view: "zero" },
      { value: "1", view: "one" },
      { value: "2", view: "Two" }
    ];
    //this.animation = false;
  }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
var value,
inputVal = document.getElementById("empty");

if(inputVal != null){
  value = inputVal.value;
}
function inputValidate(){
  value;
  if(value > 0){
    this.animation = true;
    console.log("true");
  }
  else{
    this.animation = false;
    console.log("false");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola no entiendo muy claramente lo que deseas realizar pero te podria aconsejar con lo siguiente

### **Primero**

#### componente.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forms',
  templateUrl: './forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forms.component.scss']
})

export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {

 public formulario: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private _fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Componente formulario cargado');
    this.initForms();
  }

  initForms() {
    this.formulario = this._fb.group({
      input1: [, Validators.required],
      input2: [, Validators.required]
    });
  }

}
```

Aca en el componente emplearia lo que son los formularios ractivos (Reactive Forms),
y con ayuda del validators *(Validators.required)* aseguro que el valor del input no permita estar vacio.

### **Segundo.**

Ahora creo el metodo que validara el formulario o los inputs necesarios.

```
public funcion validarValores(): any {
  if(this.formulario.valid){
    console.log('Datos son diferente de null');
  }else{
   console.log('Datos estan null');
  }
}
```

Si no quieres validar uno a uno cual esta null puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
public funcion validarValores(): any {
  if (this.formulario.value.input1 === null || this.formulario.value.input2 === null ) {
      console.log('estan vacios');
    }
}
```

### **Por último.**

Ahora lo modificas en tu HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="formulario" (ngSubmit)="validarValores()">
        <row>
          <col>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Input1" formControlName="input1"></input>
          </col>
          <col>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Input1" formControlName="input2"></input>
          </col>
        </row>
        <row>
          <col>
            <button expand="full" type="submit">Validar</ion-button>
          </col>
        </row>
      </form>
```

### **Conclusión.**

Este es un ejemplo pequeño ejemplo de como se podria validar los valores de los input y tendria las ventajas de los formularios reactivos, si vez que te ayuda o sirve puedes encontrar mas información en la documentación oficial de Angular.

Si no necesitas que se ejecute por medio de un boton la validacion, los formularios reactivos tienen la facilidad de quedar subcritos a sus cambios en el ejemplo q te envie seria mas o menos que agregaras lo siguiente en *initForms()*.

```
    this.formulario.valueChanges.subscribe(
      valor => {
        console.log('valor ingresado es ', valor);
      }
    );
```

Aca encuentras el link de la documentación.

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms